# Generate URL to google cloud storage that save file with name only

Tags: .net-core, google-cloud-platform, sdk, google-cloud-storage

I'm writing .Net Core project and managing some files on GCS(Google Cloud Storage) with Google Cloud Storage V1 .Net SDK.
I have some files in folders in "bucket1" bucket. When I'm generating signed url to files located in "bucket1/folder1/subfloder2" as a result I receive URL to file. But when I download this file, it has name with "folders" path, something like "folder1_subfloder2_desiredFileName".

I know that GCS doesn't have folders, just file names, but is there any way to generate url that will save file with it's name only, without folders path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/148270243) open to follow the resolution of this. for the moment there is not recommended workarround for this but the Engineering Team is working on this.